# Возникает баг при вычитании в калькуляторе

Tags: java, ооп

Вот код

```
public class Take1_Number {
    public static Scanner oj = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int ParsInt;
    public static int ParsInt2;
    public static String Number1;
    public static String hok;
    public static int reshenm;
    static boolean jok;
    public static void take1() {


        Number1=oj.next().toLowerCase();//берем значение введенное пользователем

        RazborChisla();
        ArifmDo arfm = new ArifmDo();
        arfm.Sweetch();
    }
    public static void RazborChisla() {
        int Num1,Num2;
        String NuMbers="",NuMbers2="";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(Number1);
        while (m.find()) {
            NuMbers=NuMbers+m.group();
            NuMbers2=NuMbers2+m.group();}

        if(Number1.contains("-")) {NuMbers=NuMbers.substring(0, NuMbers.length() - 2);}else {NuMbers=NuMbers.substring(0, NuMbers.length() - 1);}

        Num1=Integer.parseInt(NuMbers);
    ParsInt=Num1;

    NuMbers2=NuMbers2.replace("-","");
    NuMbers2=NuMbers2.substring(0, NuMbers2.length()-1);
    System.out.println(NuMbers2);
    Num2=Integer.parseInt(NuMbers2);

    ParsInt2=Num2;
    reshenm=Num1-Num2;
    }
    public void Exept(){

    if(ParsInt<1 || ParsInt>10) {System.out.println("Ты ввел число больше 10, либо меньше 1);}

    }
```

при отнимании, он складывает, а при других операциях, все нормально

```
public class ArifmDo extends Take1_Number{

public void Sweetch() {
     String option=Number1;
    if(option.contains("+")) {System.out.println(ParsInt=ParsInt+ParsInt2);}
    if(option.contains("-")) {/*System.out.println((ParsInt=ParsInt-ParsInt2);*/System.out.println(reshenm);}
    // где я закомментил, происходит баг, вместо сложеия, число складывается
    if(option.contains("/")) {System.out.println(ParsInt=ParsInt/ParsInt2);}
    if(option.contains("*")) {System.out.println(ParsInt=ParsInt*ParsInt2);}
    }
}
```

main

```
public class Main {
    static char operation;
    static int firstN;
    static int secondN;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub TODO
        Take1_Number strok = new Take1_Number();
        strok.take1();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Баг тут далеко не один. Попробуйте ввести 5+7. Зачем тут наследование? Почему вы не придерживаетесь правил именования переменных и методов? ПО какому принципу вы делите код на методы? В данном случае единственное, что могу предложить - простенькое альтернативное решение. А уже его рефакторингом и усовершенствованием займетесь сами.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        String userInput = sc.nextLine().replace(",", ".").replace(" ", "");
        List<String> list = calculator.parseInput(userInput);
        Double result = calculator.calculate(list);
        System.out.println(userInput + "=" + result);
    }

    private List<String> parseInput(String userInput) {
        List<String> parseList = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char ch : userInput.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(ch) || ch=='.' || ch==',') sb.append(ch);
            else {
                parseList.add(sb.toString());
                parseList.add(String.valueOf(ch));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        parseList.add(sb.toString());
        return parseList;
    }

    private Double calculate(List<String> parseList) {
        Double result = null;
        String mathAction = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < parseList.size(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) result = calculate(result, parseList.get(i), mathAction);
            else mathAction = parseList.get(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Double calculate(Double result, String numb, String mathAction) {
        try {
            Double number = Double.valueOf(numb);
            if (result == null) return number;
            switch (mathAction) {
                case "+": return result + number;
                case "-": return result - number;
                case "*": return result * number;
                case "/": return result / number;
                default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Math action " + mathAction + " not supported!");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("User input contains unsupport characters: " + numb);
        }
    }

}
```