# Не могу присвоить в переменную значение "+", считанное Scannerом

Tags: java

Программа - калькулятор. Ввожу в консоли в строку значения, сканер их считывает. После эти значения толкаю в массив(пробовал и отдельные переменные). Все значения кроме "+" успешно проходят данную операцию, но от плюса присваивания из сканера прекращаются, вследствие чего программа не работает.

Буду очень благодарен, если кто подскажет в чём трабл с + заключается. Интернет рыл, ничего подобного не нашёл.

```
package CalcCons;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatorConsole {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Input myInput = new Input(); // объект класса ввода выражения
        CalcAction myCalcAction = new CalcAction(); // Объект расчёта выражения

        myInput.Input(); // Вызов ввода выражения
        myCalcAction.CalcAction(); // Вызов расчёта выражения
    }
}

class Input {

    public void Input() {

        System.out.println("Введите выражение:");
        Scanner in = extracted().useDelimiter("[,\\s+]"); //  Считывание строки
        proverkaRome(in); // Проверка: арабские или римские числа введены 
        if (Example.value[3] == "1") { // если это не целые числа, то 
            converterRome();
        } else 
        {       
        MathTrue();        
        }

    }

    private void proverkaRome(Scanner in) {

        boolean Rome1 = false;
        boolean Rome2 = false;
        if(in.hasNextInt()) {
            Example.value[0] = in.next();
            } else {
                Rome1 = true;
                Example.value[0] = in.next();
            }

        Example.value[1] = in.next();

        if(in.hasNextInt()) {
            Example.value[2] = in.next();
            } else {
                Rome2 = true;
                Example.value[2] = in.next();
            }

        if (((Rome1 == false) && (Rome2 == true))  || ((Rome2 == false) && (Rome1 == true))) {
            System.out.println("Введено недопустимое выражение");
            System.exit(0); 
        }

        if ((Rome1 == true) && (Rome2 == true)) {
            Example.value[3] = "1";
     }
    }

    private void converterRome() { // конвертация римских чисел в арабские

        String firstRome =  Example.value[0]; //присваиваем значения из скана
        String secondRome =  Example.value[2];  
        // Массив с римскими числами:
        String[] rome = {"0","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX","X"};
        boolean rome1 = false, rome2 = false;
        //сравниваем считанные из скана значения со значениями из массива
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

            if (firstRome.equals(rome[i])) { // конвертируем римские числа в арабские и ставим галочку
                 Example.value[0] = String.valueOf(i);;
                 rome1 = true;
            }
            if (secondRome.equals(rome[i])) {
                 Example.value[2] = String.valueOf(i);
                 rome2 = true;
            }
        }

        if ((rome1 == false) || (rome2 == false)) { // Если оба числа не оказались римскими, то 
            System.out.println("Введено недопустимое выражение");
            System.exit(0); 
        }


            MathTrue();

    }


    private Scanner extracted() {
        return new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    private static void MathTrue() {



        int a = Integer.parseInt(Example.value[0]);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(Example.value[2]);

        if ((a > 10) || (a < 1) || (c > 10) || (c < 1)) {
            System.out.println("Введено недопустимое выражение; Я умею считать только числа от 1 до 10");
            System.exit(0); 
        }

        int index1 = Example.value[1].indexOf('+');
        int index2 = Example.value[1].indexOf('-');
        int index3 = Example.value[1].indexOf('*');
        int index4 = Example.value[1].indexOf('/');

        if ((index1 == -1) && (index2 == -1) && (index3 == -1) && (index4 == -1)) {
            System.out.println("Введено недопустимое выражение; Я не знаю такого оператора");
            System.exit(0); 
        }

    }


}

class CalcAction {

    public void CalcAction() {

    int first, second;
    first = Integer.parseInt(Example.value[0]);
    second = Integer.parseInt(Example.value[2]);
    int answer = 0;

        switch(Example.value[1]) {
            case("+"):
                answer = Summa(first, second);
                break;
            case("-"):
                answer = Subtraction(first, second);
                break;
            case("*"):
                answer = Multiplication(first, second);
                break;
            case("/"):
                answer = Division(first, second);
                break;
        }

        if (Example.value[3] == "0") {
        System.out.println(answer);
        } else {
            reConverter(answer);
        }

    }

    private static int Summa(int first, int second) {   
        return (first + second);        
    }

    private static int Subtraction(int first, int second) {     
        return (first - second);        
    }

    private static int Multiplication(int first, int second) {      
        return (first * second);        
    }

    private static int Division( int first, int second) {       
        return(first / second);
    }

    private static void reConverter(int answer) {

         String[] rome = {"0","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX","X"};

         for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

                if (answer == i) {
                     System.out.println(rome[i]);
                     }
         }

    }

}

class Example {

    public static String[] value = {"0","0","0","0"};

}
```

Comment: а можно код целиком, а не огрызок? надо же еще логику происходящего понять как-то...

Comment: а вообще я уже много раз отвечал на вопросы про консольный калькулятор. последний раз здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1029207/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5/1029282#1029282

Comment: @Дмитрий огрызок я для того и скинул, что меня интересует именно этот момент, и почему он не работает, а всё остальное - это уже третье-десятое.

Грубо говоря, вопрос в том: "как присвоить переменной плюс, который был введен в строку?" - и неважно в какой программе.

Comment: А массив то какого типа? Поэтому и просят не огрызок, что контекст нужно знать, чтобы найти ошибку...

Comment: @AliceMagic Окей, скину код. Но я как бы написал, что пробовал не только в массив, да и не только в этот.

Comment: А захватит ли `hasNextInt` символ `+`?

Comment: @gil9red, нет, он выдаёт false.

Comment: наверное потому, что `+` не число

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс Input, метод Input(). В строке:`Scanner in = extracted().useDelimiter("[,\\s+]");` исправьте регулярное выражение. Уберите плюс и оставьте `[,\\s]`
Так все работает.

Небольшой совет. Логическое выражение `if (((Rome1 == false) && (Rome2 == true))  || ((Rome2 == false) && (Rome1 == true)))` легко упрощается до вот такого вида: `if (!Rome1 && Rome2 || !Rome2 && Rome1)`