# Не получается сделать строковый калькулятор

Tags: java

хотел бы сосчитать -2 + 4 - 5 + 6 - 3 - 3 - 6 - 7

```
package calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator {
    private static int calculate(int number1, int number2, char operation) {
        int result = 0;
        switch (operation) {
            case '+': result = number1 + number2; break;
            case '-': result = number1 - number2; break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
        String[] blocks = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(blocks[0]);
            char operation = blocks[i+1].charAt(0);
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(blocks[i+2]);
            sum += calculate(number1, number2, operation);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно узнать, что за `blocks` такой? Откуда он взялся?

Comment: исправил         String[] blocks = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

Comment: вы прбовали пользоваться поиском? лично я уже отвечал на вопрос про калькулятор раз 5... например, тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1029207/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5/1029282#1029282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас абсолютно неправильно идёт индексация массива, в вашем случае лучше будет взять первое число, а затем вызывать для каждых двух следующих элементов массива и этого числа метод `calculate()`.

Условие `i < blocks.length` надо заменить на `i < blocks.length - 1`, так как мы берём по два элемента, и для второго индекс будет `i+1`.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
String[] blocks = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
int sum = Integer.parseInt(blocks[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < blocks.length - 1; i += 2) {
    char operation = blocks[i].charAt(0);
    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(blocks[i+1]);
    sum = calculate(sum, n2, operation);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: не работает ваш  вариант

Comment: для трех чисел выдает ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"

Comment: @plaza2009 забыл, что должно быть `i+=2`, вместо `i++`. Исправил.