# Как убрать крайне правый знак в строке ;

Tags: java, netbeans

Здраствуйте уважаемые форумчане.На днях начал разрабатывать свой калькулятор на Java и не смог найти нужную в интернете информацию о том как сделать эту кнопку со стрелочкой.
Грубо говоря:"lotres" (нажал кнопку) => "lotre" (нажал кнопку) => "lotr" и т.д.
Вариант с выбиранием по номеру символа здесь не катит.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Пишу калькулятор на java.Нужно что-бы была возможность убирать неправильные цифры или знаки в конце строки только с помощью интерфейса.Аналогично работает Backspace на клавиатуре.

Comment: Есть jTextField в нем я прописываю n-ое количесво цифр.Нужен такой метод для String который удалял крайне правые цифры по одной при нажатии кнопки.Я не знаю куда уже подробнее :/

Comment: именно ТАКОЙ метод, который нужен имено конкретному человеку именно для того, чтобы пользователь нажал на кнопку и удалился имено последний символ разработчикам Java, судя по всему, придумывать было лень в силу его неуниверсальности, поэтому они придумали метод, который обрезает строку в зависимости от пердаваемых аргументов. В вашем случае это выглядит примерно так string.substring(0, string.length()-1)

Comment: А еще поделюсь ссылкой на вопрос про калькулятор, полагаю, будет полезна https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1029207/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5/1029282#1029282

Comment: Спасибо Дмитрий, низкий поклон вам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё раз благодарю Дмитрия за предоставленный ответ в комментариях. В моем случае код выглядил так:

```
String Str = new String(Result.getText());
Result.setText(Str.substring(0, Str.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Интерфейс - это то, что видит пользователь. Под ним должен быть код. В твоем случае это работа со строками скорее всего. МЕТОДЫ класса String тебе помогут.
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/string.php - Ссылка на методы класса String/

Comment: Именно ТАКОГО метода для String я не нашел.